# SmartCard reader "Access denied" while claiming interface with Webusb on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, smartcard-reader, webusb

I am developing a javascript library to perform smart card operations using the CCID protocol over chrome webusb API. Everything goes well when I plug the smart card reader on Linux and MacOS, however I get stuck on windows when I try to claim the interface. 
I tried to run chrome as an administrator, disable smart card services / 
 CCID drivers on windows in case those were claiming the interface, but nothing does it. I keep having the 
"Failed to claim interface: Access denied (insufficient permissions)"
message. Is it really a permission problem ? Or is it some windows service I am not aware of blocking the access ?

*Edit:* I tried on another mac, on which the reader didn't work. After removing the specific vendor id / product id from the CCID driver info.plist, I managed to make it work. So I suppose the same problem is happening on windows, a CCID driver is "blocking" the access interface. What are my alternatives ?

The device descriptor:

```
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x1a44 VASCO Data Security International
  idProduct          0x0001 Digipass 905 SmartCard Reader
  bcdDevice            1.02
  iManufacturer           1 VASCO
  iProduct                2 DP905v1.1
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           93
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
  (Bus Powered)
MaxPower               50mA
Interface Descriptor:
  bLength                 9
  bDescriptorType         4
  bInterfaceNumber        0
  bAlternateSetting       0
  bNumEndpoints           3
  bInterfaceClass        11 Chip/SmartCard
  bInterfaceSubClass      0 
  bInterfaceProtocol      0 
  iInterface              0 
  ChipCard Interface Descriptor:
    bLength                54
    bDescriptorType        33
    bcdCCID              1.00
    nMaxSlotIndex           0
    bVoltageSupport         3  5.0V 3.0V 
    dwProtocols             3  T=0 T=1
    dwDefaultClock       3700
    dwMaxiumumClock      3700
    bNumClockSupported      1
    dwDataRate           9946 bps
    dwMaxDataRate      318280 bps
    bNumDataRatesSupp.     53
    dwMaxIFSD             254
    dwSyncProtocols  00000007  2-wire 3-wire I2C
    dwMechanical     00000000 
    dwFeatures       000404BE
      Auto configuration based on ATR
      Auto activation on insert
      Auto voltage selection
      Auto clock change
      Auto baud rate change
      Auto PPS made by CCID
      Auto IFSD exchange
      Short and extended APDU level exchange
    dwMaxCCIDMsgLen       272
    bClassGetResponse    echo
    bClassEnvelope       echo
    wlcdLayout           none
    bPINSupport             0 
    bMaxCCIDBusySlots       1
  Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType         5
    bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
    bmAttributes            3
      Transfer Type            Interrupt
      Synch Type               None
      Usage Type               Data
    wMaxPacketSize     0x0004  1x 4 bytes
    bInterval              32
  Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType         5
    bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
    bmAttributes            2
      Transfer Type            Bulk
      Synch Type               None
      Usage Type               Data
    wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
    bInterval               0
  Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType         5
    bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
    bmAttributes            2
      Transfer Type            Bulk
      Synch Type               None
      Usage Type               Data
    wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
    bInterval               0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The insight in your edit is correct, if the CCID driver is blocking access to the device then Chrome cannot access it. In addition on Windows the operating system must know to load the WinUSB.sys driver (which comes with Windows) against the device or else any userspace application such as Chrome cannot access it. This can be accomplished using an INF file like [this one](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/tools/usb_gadget/usb_gadget.inf) or by adding [Microsoft OS descriptors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff537430(v=vs.85).aspx) to the device to set the "compatible ID" to "WINUSB".

If you are building your own device the latter option is preferable as it will provide plug-and-play support for your users while the former still requires a manual installation step for Windows users.

If you are working with an existing device but have control over the Windows system then, similar to editing the Info.plist for the macOS driver, you can go into the Windows Device Manager and replace the existing driver with WinUSB.sys using an INF file like the above.

Comment: Thanks, your solution works on windows ! Unfortunately this is not viable. I was hoping webusb could solve the gap between web and smart card. Do you think an access to the CCID class driver could be implemented one day in chrome ?

Comment: There's no work I am aware of to bring a generic CCID API to the web.

Comment: Stupid question, but I see you seem to be a subject matter expert in this area. If I am particular working with barcode scanners, and the one I have in particular does have this issue, how would I go about searching for a barcode scanner that may not have this issue and will work out of the box? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to this but as far as i can see when a native driver takes hold of your USB device, your lost and there is nothing the browser can do about it. It seems a fix could be to change the vendor or product ID (if you can do this) so no native driver will claim your device. If this is not a solution, a chrome app has much more possibilities and might be able to overcome the problem.

Comment: The chrome.usb and WebUSB APIs are subject to the same restrictions imposed by the operating system.