# Access denied error when trying to open() a navigator.usb device

Tags: javascript, html, connection, usb

I'm having the issue both from my chrome extension's content script and from the chrome dev console, so I'm guessing it's probably not related to the Chrome extension.

I have a button with the following code:

```
okButton.onclick = async () => {
   (await navigator.usb.requestDevice({ filters: [] })).open()
 }
```

Screenshot

[image: 1]

When clicked, the device popup opens, I select the USB device (a DYMO M25 postal weight scale) and click connect, but then I'm getting the following error:

`Failed to execute 'open' on 'USBDevice': Access denied.`

Note: when I try again, I see the device marked as Paired (and then the same error happens again).

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49078873/windows-10-webusb-printing-issues-with-zebra-lp2844-domexception-access-denied) that talks about a driver solution, but I'm hoping I can find a way around this without having users (of my Chrome extension) to install anything else.
The web usb tester mentioned ([here](https://larsgk.github.io/webusb-tester/)) in the post gives me the same error in the chrome console.

Note2: I can connect no problem to the device via NodeJS (using the 'usb' module)

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: I didn't manage to solve this permission issue with navigator.usb, but I managed to read the scale's data using navigator.hid instead, details in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75189339/decoding-arraybuffer-data-from-a-usb-device-via-navigator-hid

Comment: getting same error, can anyone help for this error