# Receiving and decoding data from a USB device via navigator.hid

Tags: javascript, encoding, usb

Browser side, I'm connecting to the USB device and getting the buffer data as follows:

```
const device = (await navigator.hid.requestDevice({ filters: [] }))?.[0]
// at this point the device popup showed up, I selected the device from the list and clicked Connect
await device.open()
device.oninputreport = (report) => {
  const buffer = report.data.buffer
  console.log(buffer) // output: ArrayBuffer(5)
  console.log(new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(buffer)) // output: �j
  console.log(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(buffer)))) // output: ÿj
  console.log(buffer.toString() // output: �j
  console.log(buffer.toString('hex') // output: �j 
}
```

Instead of utf-8 I tried all encodings mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Encoding_API/Encodings), but I always get something like �j.

Note: when I try to access this weight scale from NodeJS (with the 'usb' module), the buffer is encoded in hexadecimal, and it works with just `buffer.toString('hex')` (and the result is a string like "030402005005030402005005030402005005"). But in the browser it seems to work differently.

Edit: I found the solution after all:

Instead of using the buffer, it's the DataView object containing it that needs to be used.
Here's all the code to read the data from a DYMO M25 USB weight scale:

```
const device = (await navigator.hid.requestDevice({ filters: [] }))?.[0]
await device.open()
device.oninputreport = (report) => {
  const { value, unit } = parseScaleData(report.data)
  console.log(value, unit)
}


function parseScaleData (data: DataView) {
  const sign = Number(data.getUint8(0)) == 4 ? 1 : -1 // 4 = positive, 5 = negative, 2 = zero
  const unit = Number(data.getUint8(1)) == 2 ? 'g' : 'oz' // 2 = g, 11 = oz
  const value = Number(data.getUint16(3, true)) // this one needs little endian
  return { value: sign * (unit == 'oz' ? value/10 : value), unit }
}
```

Comment: Please read and follow [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)…

Comment: @JosefZ I would have added it as a reply/answer, but I can't post answers I'm blocked...