# Is an exact device descriptor required for WebUSB support?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webusb

I am running Chrome's WebUSB on Windows 7 to try and open a SmartCard reader. When I use navigator.usb.requestDevices() with no filter on, the device appears sometimes. If I include the vendorId and the productId in the filters, then the device isn't selectable/listed In Chrome. Additionally, when I try to operate the device with

```
    .then(() => device.selectConfiguration(1))
    .then(() => device.claimInterface(0))
```

I get access denied (insufficient permissions). In practice, is each device really required to have a device descriptor formatted exactly like the one posted on the [WebUSB documentation](https://wicg.github.io/webusb/#webusb-descriptors-and-requests) in order to connect the device to Chrome and operate it? I've also tried changing the drivers to WinUSB using Zadig, but that didn't change anything.

```
       ---===>Device Information<===---
English product name: "SCR33xx v2.0 USB SC Reader"

ConnectionStatus:                  
Current Config Value:              0x01  -> Device Bus Speed: Full
Device Address:                    0x03
Open Pipes:                           3

          ===>Device Descriptor<===
bLength:                           0x12
bDescriptorType:                   0x01
bcdUSB:                          0x0200
bDeviceClass:                      0x00  -> This is an Interface Class Defined Device
bDeviceSubClass:                   0x00
bDeviceProtocol:                   0x00
bMaxPacketSize0:                   0x20 = (32) Bytes
idVendor:                        0x04E6 = Identive Group Inc.
idProduct:                       0x5116
bcdDevice:                       0x0304
iManufacturer:                     0x01
     English (United States)  "SCM Microsystems"
iProduct:                          0x02
     English (United States)  "SCR33xx v2.0 USB SC Reader"
iSerialNumber:                     0x00
bNumConfigurations:                0x01

          ---===>Open Pipes<===---

          ===>Endpoint Descriptor<===
bLength:                           0x07
bDescriptorType:                   0x05
bEndpointAddress:                  0x83  -> Direction: IN - EndpointID: 3
bmAttributes:                      0x03  -> Interrupt Transfer Type
wMaxPacketSize:                  0x0008 = 0x08 bytes
bInterval:                         0x10

          ===>Endpoint Descriptor<===
bLength:                           0x07
bDescriptorType:                   0x05
bEndpointAddress:                  0x05  -> Direction: OUT - EndpointID: 5
bmAttributes:                      0x02  -> Bulk Transfer Type
wMaxPacketSize:                  0x0040 = 0x40 bytes
bInterval:                         0x00

          ===>Endpoint Descriptor<===
bLength:                           0x07
bDescriptorType:                   0x05
bEndpointAddress:                  0x84  -> Direction: IN - EndpointID: 4
bmAttributes:                      0x02  -> Bulk Transfer Type
wMaxPacketSize:                  0x0040 = 0x40 bytes
bInterval:                         0x00

       ---===>Full Configuration Descriptor<===---

          ===>Configuration Descriptor<===
bLength:                           0x09
bDescriptorType:                   0x02
wTotalLength:                    0x005D  -> Validated
bNumInterfaces:                    0x01
bConfigurationValue:               0x01
iConfiguration:                    0x03
     English (United States)  "CCID Class"
bmAttributes:                      0xA0  -> Bus Powered
  -> Remote Wakeup
MaxPower:                          0x32 = 100 mA

          ===>Interface Descriptor<===
bLength:                           0x09
bDescriptorType:                   0x04
bInterfaceNumber:                  0x00
bAlternateSetting:                 0x00
bNumEndpoints:                     0x03
bInterfaceClass:                   0x0B  -> This is a Chip/Smart Card USB Device Interface Class
bInterfaceSubClass:                0x00
bInterfaceProtocol:                0x00
iInterface:                        0x04
     English (United States)  "CCID Interface"

          ===>HID Descriptor<===
bLength:                           0x36
bDescriptorType:                   0x21
bcdHID:                          0x0110
bCountryCode:                      0x00
bNumDescriptors:                   0x07
bDescriptorType:                   0x03
wDescriptorLength:               0x0000
bDescriptorType:                   0x00
wDescriptorLength:               0x12C0
bDescriptorType:                   0x00
wDescriptorLength:               0x4000
bDescriptorType:                   0x1F
wDescriptorLength:               0x0000
bDescriptorType:                   0x00
wDescriptorLength:               0x3267
bDescriptorType:                   0x00
wDescriptorLength:               0xE700
bDescriptorType:                   0x4C
wDescriptorLength:               0x0006

          ===>Endpoint Descriptor<===
bLength:                           0x07
bDescriptorType:                   0x05
bEndpointAddress:                  0x83  -> Direction: IN - EndpointID: 3
bmAttributes:                      0x03  -> Interrupt Transfer Type
wMaxPacketSize:                  0x0008 = 0x08 bytes
bInterval:                         0x10

          ===>Endpoint Descriptor<===
bLength:                           0x07
bDescriptorType:                   0x05
bEndpointAddress:                  0x05  -> Direction: OUT - EndpointID: 5
bmAttributes:                      0x02  -> Bulk Transfer Type
wMaxPacketSize:                  0x0040 = 0x40 bytes
bInterval:                         0x00

          ===>Endpoint Descriptor<===
bLength:                           0x07
bDescriptorType:                   0x05
bEndpointAddress:                  0x84  -> Direction: IN - EndpointID: 4
bmAttributes:                      0x02  -> Bulk Transfer Type
wMaxPacketSize:                  0x0040 = 0x40 bytes
bInterval:                         0x00
```

Comment: You say your device is a smart card reader but the descriptor listing in the question is a Samsung Android device. Are you sure you're connecting to the right device?

Comment: Edited to reflect that I'm getting that message for a smart card reader.

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46179569/smartcard-reader-access-denied-while-claiming-interface-with-webusb-on-chrome/46186495

Comment: Additionally,when trying to open/claim the device, I get a `device endpoint` error sometimes and an `Access Denied` error the other times.