# "Failed to execute 'open' on 'USBDevice': Access denied."

Tags: google-chrome, esp32, webusb

Windows 8

I have tried both a Wemos D1 R32 and a ESP32 UWB, but I can't open a device using WEBUSB

My code is

```
document.getElementById('getDevices').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      navigator.usb.requestDevice({
        filters: []
      }).then(function (device) {
        console.log(device);
        return device.open(); // Begin
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
     });
});
```

The device appears and then when selected the error is

```
DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on 'USBDevice': Access denied.
```

It is currently using the "Silicon Labs CP210x USB to UART Bridge" device driver.

I followed the instructions on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46179569/smartcard-reader-access-denied-while-claiming-interface-with-webusb-on-chrome) but when I update the device driver software to point at [this](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:tools/usb_gadget/usb_gadget.inf) inf file I get the message

```
---------------------------
Select Device
---------------------------
The folder you specified doesn't contain a compatible software driver for your device. If the folder contains a driver, make sure it is designed to work with Windows for x64-based systems.
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than trying to use the WebUSB API, since your system already has the right UART driver installed, try using the [Web Serial API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Serial_API).

Answer (score 0):

```html
use this software zadig
go to this link : https://zadig.akeo.ie
step-1 : download zadig
step-2 : go to options and select list all devices
step-3 : select your device
step-4 : replace driver
step-5 : done
```

Comment: You should add explanation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).